# Reflection of Light by Concave Mirror

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, geometric-optics

When a concave mirror is to produce a *sharp* image of an object, the image is formed at the focus. But an image is only formed at the focus by a concave mirror when the object is at an infinite distance. The sun is not at an infinite distance from the earth. Why, then, can a concave mirror form a sharp image of the sun at the focus?

Comment: No, the image is not formed at the focus.

Comment: You might consider accepting @Aganju's answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong or to explain. The image is *imperfect*, because the sun is not infinitely far away.

The next step would be to calculate *how* imperfect the image is (it will basically be a bit fuzzy) - and when you execute the math, you find that the errors are proportional to the ratio of mirror size to sun's distance, which is a very small ratio (for example, 0.1 meters mirror size / 150 000 000 000 meters distance = 0.000 000 000 000 67), so they are basically invisible (and below the wavelength of light).